# JQuery get the text inside an element using special characters

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to isolate a number inside a h6 tag and wrap it in a div.

```
<h6>[123-4] My Title</h6>
```

To

```
<h6>
   <div class="number">123-4</div>
   My Title
</h6>
```

How can I select and wrap the number? .text() seems to select everything and using a regex would be difficult as the title text could also contain dashes.

Comment: Why you want/need to that ? How do you generate the html in the first place ? I would simply change it on the backend side.

Comment: This is part of a wysiwyg via the wordpress editor, but the client can't supply the backend to me, so a different approach is needed.

Answer (score 1):

A dirty solution would be to use a simple **replace**. By default replace ONLY replaces the first instance. If you are sure that the number will be wrapped in brackets, then using a replace will only replace the first instances of each bracket.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("h6").each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace("[", "<div class='number'>").replace("]", "</div>"))
  });
});
```

```css
.number {
  display: inline-block;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h6>[123-4] My [Titl]e</h6>
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your help! I did not know `.replace()` would only replace the first instance. But how would you repeat it should more bracket numbers come up? In my case the text wont contain any brackets.

Answer (score 1):

> a regex would be difficult as the title text could also contain dashes

You have to identify the pattern that will allow you to discern which part of the text is your "number" and which is the title.  It looks like the square brackets will surround then number?  In which case the regex is simple:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    let text=$('h6').text();
    let $target = $('#result');
    let $number = $('.number');
    
    const re = /\[(.+)\](.+)/;
    let matched = text.match(re);
    
    $number.text(matched[1]);
    $target.append(matched[2].trim());
    
    // console.log('text', text);
    // console.dir(matched);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h6>[123-4] My Title</h6>

Result:
<div id="result">
    <div class="number"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Appreciate the clear script! Works like a charm.